# How to scale the view to fit the content size in Android using animations

Tags: android, android-animation

I have two views on parent Layout those are top and bottom screens and bottom screen having fixed height and its align to parent-bottom and top screen based on content it must be extend and collapse on parent Layout when i tapped on it and bottom screen automatically come down from top screen and i can able to scroll total content on parent Layout can some one help me please

### activity_main.layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_view"
        android:background="#3143ff" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

### MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final View view = findViewById(R.id.view);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            final int screenHeight = contentView.getHeight();
            ValueAnimator heightAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(view.getHeight(), screenHeight);
            heightAnimator.setDuration(1500);
            heightAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
                view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                view.requestLayout();
            });
            heightAnimator.start();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: why not using `wrap_content` as `layout_height` for first view.it will expand and collapse according to data.

Comment: its client requirement initially we are showing half details when i tapped on it must be extend based on content size with the help of animations

Comment: Ohh Okay. You can use `Folding Library` easily found on Github

Answer (score 0):

See [FoldingCell for Android](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android) for more help.

**In your build.gradle()**

```
dependencies{
    implementation 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.2'
}
```

**In you `XML` layout**

```
<com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/folding_cell"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
​

             <!--Layout One-->    ​

             <!--Layout Two-->


</com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell>
```

Almost done! Two steps remain! For correct animation, you need to set up two properties on the root element(s) of your Folding Cell: ​

> android:clipChildren="false"
>
> android:clipToPadding="false"

**In your Java class**

```
    // get our folding cell
    final FoldingCell fc = (FoldingCell) findViewById(R.id.folding_cell);
​
    // attach click listener to folding cell
    fc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fc.toggle(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false" where should i keep this steps?

Comment: `set up two properties on the root element(s)` means `<com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell >` inside here.,